# Upload file error using CopyService SharePoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, file-upload

I am trying to upload file using CopyService of SharePoint. It works fine until I realised that when file names end with '.' (dot) for example test. .docx, test...docx, test....docx etc. I am getting CopyResult as Invalid URL.

I am not 100% sure If these names are valid and should upload like simple file names or I should display an error message saying invalid file name to my users.

Please help.

My Code -

```
public static void CopyImageOnServer(string sourceUrl, string destinationUrl, byte[] fileData)
    {
        PBSWebApplication.CopyServiceReference.CopySoapClient proxy = Utility.GetServerCopyProxy();

        // List of desination Urls, Just one in this example.
        string[] destinationUrls = { Uri.EscapeUriString(destinationUrl) };
        // Empty Field Information. This can be populated but not for this example.     SharePoint2007CopyService.FieldInformation information = new          SharePoint2007CopyService.FieldInformation();     SharePoint2007CopyService.FieldInformation[] info = { information };      // To receive the result Xml.     SharePoint2007CopyService.CopyResult[] result;

        // Empty Field Information. This can be populated but not for this example.
        CopyServiceReference.FieldInformation information = new CopyServiceReference.FieldInformation();

        CopyServiceReference.FieldInformation[] info = { information };

        // To receive the result Xml.
        CopyServiceReference.CopyResult[] result;

        uint returnValue = proxy.CopyIntoItems(sourceUrl, destinationUrls, info, fileData, out result);

        if (result[0].ErrorCode != CopyServiceReference.CopyErrorCode.Success)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not somehow required to use the SOAP services I would highly recommend using CSOM or REST to accomplish your task.  CopyService is difficult to work with and REST is now considered the standard.  I used to have a working example of what you are trying to do but I converted it to CSOM for which there are many, simple examples available on TechNet.  If you want to avoid using an additional library that is not distributed with .NET then use REST.

Here is an example of uploading a file in C# using REST:

```
                    string url = "http://your.sharepoint.site";
                    client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true }); 
                    client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri(url);
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-RequestDigest", digest);
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-HTTP-Method", "POST");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("binaryStringRequestBody", "true");

                    ByteArrayContent file = new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes);
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(String.Concat("_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Images')/RootFolder/Files/add(url='", filename, ".jpg',overwrite='true')?$expand=ListItemAllFields"), file);
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {}
```

I have examples of getting the digest and updating the metadata here if you need additional examples:

https://arcandotnet.wordpress.com/2015/04/01/sharepoint-2013-rest-services-using-c-and-the-httpclient-for-windows-store-apps/